# Extra Records Being Loaded to MongoDB in both MapReduce and Spark (using different write structure)

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

In two different programs that use different types of writing to a MongoDB collection, there are extra records occasionally being written to this collection. Due to the size of the collection (200m+ records) and the processing of the upload for these, finding out why this (seemingly-nondeterministic) extra upload occurs will save us a large amount of time re-loading the process.

Some extra information:
Within both programs I verify before writing that the correct number of records has been created and exists (216.45m output records in MapReduce logs, 216.45m records when I do a count on the RDD containing the bson documents to be written). On the most recent upload, there were 239.8m records loaded to Mongo. The average size of the documents in this collection with extra records is the exact same as the average size of the documents in the correctly uploaded collection, the only difference is document count and total size.

Right now I'm tackling a separation here so that the creation of bson documents will be written to a hdfs location, and then another program will upload from this to Mongo. This way I do not have to go through all of the joining & recreating the documents process each time I need to test this.

At some point if I cannot find any solutions, I will be writing a program to analyze the difference between these two collections to see if it's just duplicate records being written. This has been my assumption due to the avg size of documents being the same so I have not yet allocated my time towards this.

Within Spark, here is the process for writing.
writeMeToMongo is an RDD of json-formatted documents that has been verified to have the correct number of documents. The internal code somehow occasionally writes a very large number of extra documents to Mongo.

```scala
// numMongoThreads is traditionally ~200
writeMeToMongo.repartition(numMongoThreads).foreachPartition(jsonsToWrite => {

      if(outputDB == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(outputDB)) {
        throw new Exception("Output DB was never set.")
      }

      // connectionString is a Broadcast[String]
      val connectionURI: MongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(connectionString.value)
      val mongoClient: MongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionURI)
      val mongoDatabase: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(outputDB)
      // to setup the lazily-evaluated mongoDatabase
      mongoDatabase.getCollection("dummy").find.first

      if(mongoDatabase.listCollectionNames == null) {
        throw new Exception("No collections in this mongo database.")
      }

      //validatedArgs is a Broadcast containing some arguments (such as collectionName)
      val collectionConnector: MongoCollection[Document] = mongoDatabase.getCollection(validatedArgs.value.collection)

      // buffer up to maxMongoDocsPerWrite # of documents before doing a bulk write
      // I have used 1500 for this for testing, please feel free to recommend a different value
      var documentsBuffer: ListBuffer[Document] = new ListBuffer[Document]
      var docCounter = 0
      while(jsonsToWrite.hasNext && docCounter < validatedArgs.value.maxMongoDocsPerWrite) {
        documentsBuffer += Document.parse(jsonsToWrite.next)
        docCounter = docCounter + 1
        if(docCounter == validatedArgs.value.maxMongoDocsPerWrite) {
          val lotsODocs = documentsBuffer.toList.asJava
          collectionConnector.insertMany(lotsODocs)
          docCounter = 0
          documentsBuffer = new ListBuffer[Document]
        }
      }

      val leftoverDocuments = documentsBuffer.toList.asJava
      if(!leftoverDocuments.isEmpty) {
        collectionConnector.insertMany(leftoverDocuments)
      }
    })
```

For MapReduce, the code is more difficult to concisely replicate here so I have not included it.

I'm aware that there are other methods for writing to MongoDB from an RDD containing the documents, but because of some requirements I believe we must use this method since we have some special restrictions on the connection string and must verify the connection string, so we cannot use parameters for this.

Comment: I suspect that some inserts and/or spark tasks fail and some documents get reinserted again, thus creating duplicates. In SQL databases this can be solved by using transactions or with "insert if not exists". However, I am unfamiliar with mongo...

Comment: @gudok could this same functionality happen with MapReduce? i.e., some of the reducers fail and re-insert?

Comment: Sure, why not? When this happens, failed/killed tasks will be listed in the web UI.

Comment: @gudok if you add that as an answer, I will accept it.